# Return value for wshell.run

Tags: vbscript

I have a VB Script which triggers the jobs from the tool through a BAT file and get the status error/success.
code is :

```
intReturn = WShell.Run(strBATFile,0,True)

If intReturn = 1 Then 
    intReturn = 0  
    strJobStat = "Complete"
End If

If intReturn = 3 or intReturn=2 Then 
   intReturn = 1  
   strJobStat = "Error"
End If
```

The above code is working fine, if a job triggers and Completed/Failed. But if the job didn't trigger (started) also, it shows success.

please suggest what can be changed/added in the above code if the job did not started.
What is the error code to handle.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. But it contains a catch all Else statement that will capture any instances where the return value from WShell.Run is not 1, 2 or 3.

If bWaitOnReturn is set to TRUE - which it is in your case - the Run method returns any error code returned by the application. So whatever strBATFile returns will be returned by WShell.Run into intReturn.

```
intReturn = WShell.Run(strBATFile,0,True)

If intReturn = 1 Then 
    intReturn = 0  
    strJobStat = "Complete"
Else If intReturn = 3 or intReturn=2 Then 
   intReturn = 1  
   strJobStat = "Error"
Else
   strJobStat = "Unexpected Error"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.Am looking for the Error code what exactly it is going to ruturn and why it is succeeding.

Comment: @user2717144 It depends on what your bat file returns. bWaitOnReturn is set to true so whatever your bat file returns it will be returned by the Run method of WShell